# how to create a shortcode from a variable in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, plugins, global-variables

i'm using WP User Frontend Pro plugin
i want to echo the pack title using a shortcode to put it in bakery visual.
all what i know is : this is the title $pack->post_title;

$pack is coming from here :

```
public function current_pack() {
    global $pack;
    $pack = $this->pack;

    if ( ! isset( $this->pack['pack_id'] ) ) {
        $pack_page = get_permalink( wpuf_get_option( 'subscription_page', 'wpuf_payment' ) );

        return new WP_Error( 'no-pack', sprintf( __( 'You must <a href="%s">purchase a subscription package</a> before posting', 'wp-user-frontend'), $pack_page ) );
    }

    // seems like the user has a pack, now check expiration
    if ( $this->expired() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'expired', __( 'The subscription pack has expired. Please buy a pack.', 'wp-user-frontend' ) );
    }

    return $pack;
}
```

i try to do something like this :

```
function wpc_shortcode_pack_title() {
global $pack;
return $pack->post_title;
}
add_shortcode( 'sub_name', 'wpc_shortcode_pack_title' );
```

to explain more 
the slected code in line 5 is working correctly in the plugin pages
but i want it as a shortcode 
[image]

but it didn't work
any help please ?

Comment: What is in the global $pack?

Comment: @HowardE i edited the qustion so u can know what is it

Comment: Can you post code and not screenshots? Also are you sure that `$pack->post_title` contains anything? Can you dump the output?

Comment: @HowardE i edited again with the code , yes it should print the package title

Comment: If you add var_dump($pack) to your shortcode. Do you see the dump on the page with the shortcode? It should be at the top of the page. And is post_title in the object?

Comment: dumping NULL @HowardE , but it should print the package title as it happen in other page

Comment: Well... there's your problem.  Your shortcode is working, but your value is null. Is the class that your public function is a part of instantiated? It seems like you want to call $class->pack... I'm not familiar with the Frontend Pro plugin, or what it does.

Comment: thats good , sorry but how to check thtis if it's part of instantiated? @HowardE

Comment: and yes the $pack variable is coming from a file called class-user-subscription.php @HowardE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function of [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) should *return* the content, not print it.

Meaning, you have to `return $pack->post_title` instead of `echo $pack->post_title`.

Like so:

```php
function wpc_shortcode_pack_title() {
  global $pack;
  return $pack->post_title;
}

add_shortcode( 'sub_name', 'wpc_shortcode_pack_title' );
```

---

**Edit:** After taking a look at the source of “WP User Frontend Pro”:

`$pack` seems to be getting its value from `WPUF_Subscription::get_subscription()` passing the subscription id, which basically gets the post with that id.

The subscription id seems to be getting its value from `WPUF_Subscription::get_user_pack()` passing the user id.

So, I guess you could call [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) and try something like this:

```php
function wpc_shortcode_pack_title() {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();

  if ( ! class_exists( 'WPUF_Subscription' ) ) {
    return 'WP User Frontend Pro is not installed/activated';
  }

  $user_sub = WPUF_Subscription::get_user_pack( $user_id );
  $pack = WPUF_Subscription::get_subscription( $user_sub['pack_id'] );

  return $pack->post_title;
}

add_shortcode( 'sub_name', 'wpc_shortcode_pack_title' );
```

---

**Edit #2:** To get the expire date as well, you would do something similar:

```php
function wpc_shortcode_pack_title() {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();

  if ( ! class_exists( 'WPUF_Subscription' ) ) {
    return 'WP User Frontend Pro is not installed/activated';
  }

  // Get WPUF subscription/pack
  $user_sub = WPUF_Subscription::get_user_pack( $user_id );
  $pack = WPUF_Subscription::get_subscription( $user_sub['pack_id'] );

  // Get expiration date
  $expire = ( $user_sub['expire'] == 'unlimited' ) ? ucfirst( 'unlimited' ) : wpuf_date2mysql( $user_sub['expire'] );

  return sprintf(
    'Subscription name: %1$s | Expire date: %2$s',
    $pack->post_title,
    wpuf_get_date( $expire )
  );
}

add_shortcode( 'sub_name', 'wpc_shortcode_pack_title' );
```

Comment: yes i did it but same thing , i edited my qustion for more details

Comment: @anton Alright, I edited my answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: yees it worked , thanks 
and can i do it with echo $expiry_date ? i try it but i can't to

Comment: @anton Sure! I edited my answer to include the expire date as well. You get the idea, you could do this for any other subscription detail you need. I haven't actually tested any of this, so please let me know if it works.

Comment: please i'm trying to use if else to pring someting if the user have no pack , any instructions ?